# What does it mean for a system of equations to have a non trivial solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

What does it mean for a system of equations to have a non trivial solution?

Trivial means obviously but how can a equation have a obvious solution?

My book says if solution is  non trivial than determinant of coefficient of variables is 0.

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word is often used about systems of equations such as
$$ 3x+5y-12z = 0 \\ x-y+5z = 0 \\ 5x+y+3z=0 $$
where it is immediately obvious that setting all of the unknowns to $0$ will solve the system. The question is then whether the system has *other* solutions than that.

Comment: Well, sometimes the system is displaced e.g. $$3(x-2)+5y-12z = 0 \\ (x-2)-y+5z = 0 \\ 5(x-2)+y+3z=0$$ gives the trivial solution $x=2,y=0$ and $z=0$. Btw I think your have a nice answer.